# Can I play a playlist of rear and front dashcam videos in MPV?

Tags: shell-script, multimedia, mpv

I'm trying to play both front and rear footage from my dashcam at the same time as a playlist in `mpv`.

Front and rear video files are in `F` and `R` directories. I can easily add all files from e.g. `F` directory to the playlist:

```
mpv F/*
```

I can also run a picture-in-picture overlay for a single pair of front/rear footage:

```
mpv $front_video --external-file=$rear_video --lavfi-complex='[vid2] scale=640x360 [small]; [vid1] [small] overlay [vo]'
```

I'm having trouble combining both, i.e. I want a playlist of picture-in-picture overlays. The issue is I always get the rear view from the first video:

```
mpv \
    REC_200607-175943F.MOV --external-file=../R/REC_200607-175943R.MOV --lavfi-complex='[vid2] scale=640x360 [small]; [vid1] [small] overlay [vo]' \
    GSR_200607-180444F.MOV --external-file=../R/GSR_200607-180444R.MOV --lavfi-complex='[vid2] scale=640x360 [small]; [vid1] [small] overlay [vo]' \
    GSR_200607-180943F.MOV --external-file=../R/GSR_200607-180943R.MOV --lavfi-complex='[vid2] scale=640x360 [small]; [vid1] [small] overlay [vo]'
```

1st overlay, all fine:
[image]

2nd overlay, plays rear view from the 1st one:
[image]

For now I'm using a script that runs `mpv` for the next pair of videos as soon as the first one quits so I can watch all of them from start to finish but I miss the features like jumping to previous/next video, checking where in the playlist I am, setting a playback speed, volume, contrast, etc. Also, it's cumbersome to stop in the middle of playback because quitting one `mpv` instance runs the next one:

```
#!/bin/sh
for front in $(ls -tr); do
    rear=../R/${front/F./R.}
    mpv $front --external-file=$rear --lavfi-complex='[vid2] scale=640x360 [small]; [vid1] [small] overlay [vo]'
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just found out MPV has a "question template" on their GitHub issue tracker so I asked there as well. Suggesting a better place to ask this is still a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a part of [MPV documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#per-file-options) that is relevant to neither filters nor playlists but describes the use of `--{` and `--}` grouping options that allow exactly what was needed.

A working script that runs overlays in a playlist below. Save it in a file, make it executable (`chmod u+x file_name`) and if your dashcam has the same naming convention as mine run it in `F` directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

videos='' 

for front in $(ls -tr); do
    rear=../R/${front/F./R.}
    videos+=" --{ $front --external-file=$rear --lavfi-complex=[vid2]scale=640x360[small];[vid1][small]overlay[vo] --}"
done

exec mpv $videos "$@"
```

- `vid1, vid2, ... vidN` - video inputs
- `vo` - video output, a.k.a the final result
- `[vid2]scale=640x360[small]` - take "vid2" (1st external video), scale it, save as "small"
- `[vid1][small]overlay[vo]` - take "vid1" and "small", overlay them, save as "vo"

Looking at how dashcams store files it should cover most if not all of them. Mind you overlay filter is slow so you might want to experiment with `hstack` or `vstack` instead (but then both videos need to have same height in pixels which usually means you'll need to upscale the rear view to match the front, e.g. `[vid2]scale=1920x1080[big];[big][vid1]hstack[vo]`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't thank you enough. I am making a video comparison tool and am using Python for the task. Here is the Python implementation of the same bash code for anyone who needs it!

I used ***Windows 10 and Python 2.7*** but it should be similar on Linux:

```python
# python 2.7, windows 10, test mpv

import os
import sys
import subprocess

RUNTIME_CWD = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MPV_EXE_PATH = [os.path.join(RUNTIME_CWD,"mpv","mpv.exe")]  # the python script is located one dir above the mpv directory


FRONT_playlist = ['C:\\Users\\PC\\Videos\\test\\test_front1.mp4', 'C:\\Users\\PC\\Videos\\test\\test_front2.mp4']
REAR_playlist = ['C:\\Users\\PC\\Videos\\test\\test_rear1.mp4', 'C:\\Users\\PC\\Videos\\test\\test_rear2.mp4']

videos=""

# supressed the terminal output using, --no-terminal

for REAR_playlist, FRONT_playlist in zip(REAR_playlist,FRONT_playlist):
    # picture in picture
    videos += " --{{ {0} --no-terminal --external-file={1} --lavfi-complex=[vid2]scale=640x360[small];[vid1][small]overlay[vo] --}}".format(REAR_playlist, FRONT_playlist)

    # top bottom
    # videos += " --{{ {0} --no-terminal --external-file={1} --lavfi-complex=[vid2]scale=1920x1080[big];[big][vid1]vstack[vo] --}}".format(REAR_playlist,FRONT_playlist)

    # side to side 
    # videos += " --{{ {0} --no-terminal --external-file={1} --lavfi-complex=[vid2]scale=1920x1080[big];[big][vid1]hstack[vo] --}}".format(REAR_playlist,FRONT_playlist)
    
subprocess.call([MPV_EXE_PATH[0]] + videos.split() + sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help and thank you for your python implementation. It's weird to me this question has so little traction. After all Linux users use dashcams too.

Comment: I saw a bunch of questions worded like "How to play multiple videos at once in mpv, or side to side" but this one got me the answer.

Is a shame --playlist does not behave well with this, windows has a limit at CreateProcess, the length is 32767 characters, and with big videos playlist it could be easily reach. 

Maybe there is a way to read from files on  multiple inputs but dont know how yet.

Comment: IDK about Windows but if it was on Linux, you could save parts of the command to temporary files, then use concatenation and command substitution to evaluate them as a single line, like so: `mpv $(cat arguments.txt video-pairs.txt)`. It'd give you way more wiggle room. The `$()` is command substitution (inlines a result of command in parentheses) and `cat file1 file2 ... fileN` is concatenation (adds file contents together).