# Can I create multiple video sources with one complex AV filter in MPV to cycle between them?

Tags: configuration, mpv

This is continuation of [Can I play a playlist of rear and front dashcam videos in MPV?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591694/can-i-play-a-playlist-of-rear-and-front-dashcam-videos-in-mpv) - there's a dashcam recording of front and back view of a vehicle (in my case there's also a helmet view, because motorcycle) and I managed to display them picture-in-picture with "overlay" filter. Now the question is:

**Can I somehow combine multiple video streams in one entry so that I could toggle between them by pressing a "cycle video" keybind?**

To clarify, I want each playlist entry to have multiple video streams, e.g. I have an overlay layout like so:

```
┌────────────────────┐
│┌─────┐      helmet │
││front│             │
│└─────┘             │
│┌─────┐             │
││ rear│             │
│└─────┘             │
└────────────────────┘
```

and I want to be able to cycle to a different video stream that plays the same files but in a layout like this:

```
┌────────────────────┐
│┌─────┐       front │
││ rear│             │
│└─────┘             │
│                    │
│                    │
│                    │
└────────────────────┘
```

For those who don't know how complex AV filters work, pasting in an explanation of the 2nd layout from the [answer to that previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591922/82399):

```
--lavfi-complex=[vid2]scale=640x360[small];[vid1][small]overlay[vo]
```

- `vid1, vid2, ... vidN` - video inputs
- `vo` - video output, a.k.a the final result
- `[vid2]scale=640x360[small]` - take "vid2" (1st external video), scale it, save as "small"
- `[vid1][small]overlay[vo]` - take "vid1" and "small", overlay them, save as "vo"